# Transaction showing on etherscan.io but no showing on API.etherscan

Tags: ethereum, erc20, etherscan

I am trying to get the transactions of an address using
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x9bb1499d06f3036a12f653f00b889731d04c47a0&startblock=0&endblock=92649034&sort=asc&apikey=XXXXX

however, I get the results "No transactions found" when in fact, a transaction exists, and can be viewed on etherscan.io site.

I wonder if anyone has encountered the same problem. Is this a bug on the etherscan side? Perhaps the api.etherscan side doesnt not have the most recent transaction information?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!![image]

Answer (score 0):

The [txlist](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts) endpoint only returns transactions `from` and `to` to the specified address.

You're trying to view transactions `from` and `to` address `0x9bb1...`. But this specific tx (on the screenshot) originated from `0x2204...` and was sent to contract `0x30ad...`.

The `0x9bb1...` only acts in the event logs produced by the transactions, and most likely the tx was executing a `transfer()` function with this address as a param.

TLDR: When you're transfering tokens, you're sending a transaction to the token contract - not to the token recepient.

Comment: Thanks for the insights!  I understand what you mean.
So if i want to check these transfer() information, what etherscan endpoint do you reckon i should use?

And btw, I use to be able to view this transfer() details just fine previously...

Comment: You can use the `tokentx` action of the `accounts` module ([docs](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts)).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Anyway, yesterday seemed to be a problem on the Etherscan side. It worked after a few hours. Their api endpoint must not have been fully updated like the one on their website.

Comment: I'm facing this issue too and just saw this. I'm not sure I fully understand.. In my case I am trying to retrieve all transactions from an address and it shows on etherscan but not via the API call. The odd thing is that the "From" address in one of the transactions from etherscan DID originate from the address that I am checking for. What am I missing with this?